# data is not inserting to Mysql ( java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver)

Tags: java, mysql, database

I am just making a signup page. There is a servlet which is requesting data from jsp and sending it to a Java class, but I am getting this error during running. I want to insert data in xampp mysql whose name is exam and table name is stu with 3 fields: name, username, and password.

This is the servlet code:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    String password  =request.getParameter("password");

    Dsignup ds = new Dsignup();
    if(ds.check(name,username,password))
    {

    }

}
```

and this is Java class:

```
public class Dsignup {

  String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/exam";
  String uname = "root";
  String psd = "";
  public boolean check(String namee, String usernamee, String passworde) 
  {     
    try 
    {
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");           
      System.out.println(namee);
      Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, uname, psd);        
      PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement("insert into stu(name,username,password) values(?,?,?)");
      st.setString(1, namee);
      st.setString(2, usernamee);
      st.setString(3, passworde);

      System.out.println("check func5io");

      int rs = st.executeUpdate();  
      System.out.println("shahjahah");          
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("ni bhai jaan");
    return false;       
  }
}
```

i have a similar file for inserting data into db and that's working perfectly
here is the code of working class

```
public class Db {
    public static void main(String []args){
        String naame="sdsafjhhahfgd";
        String usaername="jadgdsba fhan";
        String paassword="gdsdbfbsgdsh";
        try {
            Connection  con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/exam", "root",     "");
            Statement st=con.createStatement();
            String sql="insert into stu "+"(name,username,password)"+"  values('"+naame+"','"+usaername+"','"+paassword+"')";
            st.executeUpdate(sql);

            System.out.println("data inserting");

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you added jar with driver for MySQL database into classpath?

Comment: yes.I have another java file which is working perfect in same pakage but this file  Dsignup isn't working.i am inserting data by that file.

Comment: this other java class file and is in same pakage but working great to insert data.here is the ode''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Comment: How do you build and deploy your servlet?

Comment: can you express your question.am  new to java development

Comment: How do you run your jsp with your servlet? if you are using Maven to build war file, please add pom.xml to the question.

Comment: Don't post code or clarification in comments - please just edit your question

Comment: no no.It's simple dynamic website in eclipse.The whole problem is with Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver") and  in Inserting query  in class Dsignup

Comment: So the root cause is that when you run your servlet you do not add jar with driver to classpath. Another class works because it is not a servlet and you are running your web application in a different way.

Comment: i just edit my question.It will explain what i want to say

Comment: what should i do now

Comment: How do you start your web application?

Comment: am running jsp file while ask about name,username and password for signup through form.then this jsp file send data to servlet which then send this data to that class file which is having issues.It's simple application.

Comment: Check this link: https://www.studytonight.com/servlet/creating-servlet-in-eclipse.php. You need to add jar with MySQL driver to Web App Libraries

Answer (score 0):

One difference that I notice is that this line:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

is missing from the second class. From Java 6 onwards, you don't need to specifically load the JDBC driver with `Class.forName`. It could well be that you're missing the JDBC driver in your classpath, but try removing this line and see what happens. If you still get the exception, the MySQL JDBC driver JAR file must be included in the classpath when you run your servlet.